# Get total from SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I have a GridView which is bound to a datasource, which occasionally has a few thousand rows. I've obviously paged the results to avoid having such a huge grid.

I need to get the total of a certain decimal column however - currently I do a seperate query which is quite taxing considering the size of the datasource. Is there a way I can go through all the rows in the datasource, and get the total? I used to do this by calculating OnRowDataBound but this is now not an option due to the paging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, no, not without loadin them all which again makes it slow.

Normally the UI should not shwo a count but "more than x rows".

Example:

- Load 501 rows
- cut off one row
- Say the result ahs more than 500 rows

Finished.

This is how most such interfaces work, including all of active directory maangement.